# OpenCV 3.0.0: How to display trackbar at top of window in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, window, ubuntu-14.04, opencv3.0, trackbar

I am following this tutorial to make a draggable trackbar, but **the trackbar only appears on the bottom of the window**, and I cannot find an option to change that behavior. In the tutorial, they clearly show the trackbar at the top of the figure.

`http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/trackbar/trackbar.html`

I expect this may be an issue caused by the "figure viewer" Ubuntu uses, but **is there any way I can get it to appear at the top?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't do that!** OpenCV GUIs features are just for building fast prototypes. To build more advanced GUIs you need to use a 3rd party libraries like Qt.

A while back I wrote this [simple **Qt**/**OpenCV** application](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/cvImage) to load an image with OpenCV and display it on a [QMainWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html). By the way, Qt's *trackbar* name is [QSlider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qslider.html).

Comment: So then what causes the trackbar in the tutorial to appear on top? Is it being displayed on Windows?

Comment: That screenshot was taken a long time ago. Who knows what was the behavior of their GUI back then.